# Is there a simple way to fetch a JSON dataset from a remote server in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, json

Is there a simple way to fetch a JSON dataset from a remote server in Grails?

e.g. data at `http://example.com/data.json`

Data:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith"
}
```

example Groovy code (theoretical):

```
def data = getJson('http://example.com/data.json')
println data.firstName // this will print "John"
```

Comment: Does it support JSONP? cross-domain AJAX requests are forbidden in most environments (for security reasons; XSS is the biggest problem of the web).

Comment: @elusive this is server-side, so I'm not sure JSONP/XSS are relevant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you should be able to do:

```
import grails.converters.*

...

def data = JSON.parse( new URL( 'http://example.com/data.json' ).text )
println data.firstName
```

Comment: thanks tim - couldn't really be simpler, could it!  I'll give it a whirl and get back to you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Grails rest plug in](http://www.grails.org/plugin/rest) which allow you to execute REST request in json and allows you to handle all the different response types. It is very easy to use.

One example would be something like:

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.ResponseParseException
import net.sf.json.JSONException
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.GET

...
      def restMethod() {
        try {
          def http = new HTTPBuilder("http://www.example.com")
          def path = "/exampleService/info"

          http.request(Method.POST, JSON) {req ->
            uri.path = path
            contentType = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
            body = "{\"arg1\":\"value4Arg1\"}"

            response.success = {resp, json ->
                // do something with the json response
            }

            response.failure = {resp ->
              // return some error code
            }
          }
        } catch (JSONException jsonException) {
          // do something with the exception
        } catch (ResponseParseException parseException) {
          // do something with the exception
        } catch (Exception e) {
         // do something with the exception
        }
      }
```

Comment: Hi @Maricel, can you add an example of using the grails-REST-plugin?

Comment: I am trying to use this and get Internal_error at SSLSocketFactory.java:543.  Also, are you using the variables contentType and body?